# XAML-Twitter Client. Get all Tweets from User

Tags: twitter, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, .net-4.5

I will start out by saying I am new to building Windows 8 Applications. I recently downloaded the following XAML-Twitter Client Example:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-Twitter-Client-e343d336#content

In the code it searches tweets by keywords using:

```
SyndicationFeed feed = await client.RetrieveFeedAsync(new Uri("http://search.twitter.com/search.rss?q=" + TweetSearch));
```

"TweetSearch" being a string value that contains the keyword.

I am trying to change this code to retrieve and display all tweets by a certain user but cannot quite get it to work. This is closest I have come is:

```
SyndicationClient client = new SyndicationClient();

//SyndicationFeed feed = await client.RetrieveFeedAsync(new Uri("https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name=UserName"));

model.Tweets.Clear();

foreach (var item in feed.Items)
{
    _model.Tweets.Add(new Tweet
    {
        Name = item.Authors[0].Email,
        Message = item.Title.Text,
        Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(item.ElementExtensions.First(element => element.NodeName == "image_link").NodeValue))});
    }
}
```

But I receive the error `"Specified argument was out of the range of valid values."`

On

```
        foreach (var item in feed.Items)
        {
            _model.Tweets.Add(new Tweet
            {
                Name = item.Authors[0].Email,
                Message = item.Title.Text,
                Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(item.ElementExtensions.First(element => element.NodeName == "image_link").NodeValue))
            });
        }
```

Comment: I seem to recall that later versions of the API say you must be authenticated. With that, I recommend Linq to Twitter which has WinRT support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is documentation of [GET statuses/user_timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline)

You have to change the click event like this

```
private async void Button_Click_1(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SyndicationClient client = new SyndicationClient();
    SyndicationFeed feed = await client.RetrieveFeedAsync(new Uri("https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name=" + SearchTerm.Text));

    _model.Tweets.Clear();

    foreach (var item in feed.Items)
    {
        _model.Tweets.Add(new Tweet
        {
            Message = item.Summary.Text
        });
    }
}
```

I haven't changed the data template of GridView, I used the existing one. If you want to show the user's profile picture then check the documentation of [GET users/show](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/show). You have to deserliaze the response.